# Automate the import of graphics (curves) in QGIS atlas?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, atlas, graphics, rqgis

I'm working on QGIS 2.18 (Windows) and often use the atlas generation tool. But for a specific study, I would very much like to be able import within the composer not only map objects, but also graphics (curves) automatically. 
Would some people advise a way to do that?

Am I obliged to program something with python (I'm not programmer but I'm ready to start)? R could be also an interesting solution?

Comment: Are your "curves" graphics files ? If so u should be able to use a specific field pointing to them (files path) ... no ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your answer allows me to realize that my task can be decomposed into 2 diistinguishable steps. The realization of the graphs, and the import, the "calling" of the files paths in the atlas thanks to a field. Currently, no, I have not yet realized the graphics. But I can do it quite easily. Can you explain briefly how to define a file path iinto an attribute field? The way to define this field within the atlas qgis tool interface? Thanks.

Comment: sorry : When u add an image into a composer the "image source" property can be "data defined" (choose "data defined override" listbox at the right). So in your source table (let's say a "city" table) u can either insert a string value of the file path of your graphic files or (better) u can dynamically create a path string using one of your existing table column (for ex. a city code). choose "edit" and build the right expression. U have to choose a given logic when naming your source files (ofc) using any of the attribute existing in your table.